# Wildcard in VLOOKUP does not find items from lookup array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am looking to assess our spending by categorising our bank statement, line by line.

I'm using a VLOOKUP with wildcards. For reasons I cannot understand, this wildcard lookup is not working. It only works if the text in column "Description" matches an item from the lookup array exactly.

why does my formula in G2 not correctly wildcard match one of the values in the lookup array?

[image: example]

Comment: Because you tell vlookup to do an exact match.

Comment: What is your excel version? VLookup will not work in this way.

Comment: @SolarMike. That has nothing to do with the problem. The problem is that `ZOOPLUS` for example is embedded in `C2`. And OP is not going to find the whole string from `C2` in `G4` anyway. FYI, `VLOOKUP("*"&G4&"*",C2:D2,2,0)` will find the correct value. But the reversed is simply not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you an user of ***Microsoft 365*** then try-

```
=@FILTER(H4:H6,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G4:G6,C2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, and a note to OP: Results is going to be arbitrairy regardless, since finding a smaller substring in a larger one can proof to be difficult and yield false positives. For example `a` in `abc` but also `a d`. Point here is that if OP can't distinquish word boundaries this will remain tough.